# In Java, how do you create an ArrayList, with one element of that list being another ArrayList, that is unique for each element?

Tags: java

So for example.

I have an `ArrayList` of people. Created through a people object that contains a name, address, age, etc.

How would I then add another list to that, allowing a unique list of hobbies for each person?

So I could have:

- James, 32, England, (Football, Tennis)
- Chloe, 21, Wales, (Art)

Tried a few things and struggling with it.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class People {
    int id;
    String name;
    ArrayList<String> hobbies;

    public People(int id, String name, ArrayList<String> hobbies) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }

    public People(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public People() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "People [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", hobbies=" + hobbies + "]";
    }
}
```

---

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<People> arrayPeople = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<>();
        hobbies.add("Football");
        hobbies.add("Tennis");
        arrayPeople.add(new People(1,"Paul", hobbies));
        hobbies.add("Golf");
        arrayPeople.add(new People(2,"James", hobbies));

        System.out.println(arrayPeople);
    }
}
```

This creates a hobby list that is the same for each person, not unique.

Comment: cretae a class People with all info that you need , than creat an ArrayList of that classe

Comment: I would, but so far I'm not really sure where to start with an arraylist within an arraylist.

I have created a people class, but I'd like the hobbies to be a separate list as part of the people list, not just hobbies added onto the end

Comment: `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> a = new ArrayList<>(); a.add(new ArrayList<String>)` --- but this isn't what you need. You need to modify your `Person` class and add the hobbies there. You can put `Person` instances in a list if you want. That's why we ask for your code. It's much easier to explain with a concrete example. Please check [ask].

Comment: You've only created a single `hobbies` ArrayList, so both Paul and James are sharing the same list. You need to create a List each.

Answer (score 1):

> This creates a hobby list that is the same for each person, not unique.

That's because member `hobbies` in [*Paul*] `People` object has same value as member `hobbies` in [*James*] `People` object, since they are assigned the same value in method `main` of class `Runner`. Hence when you change `hobbies` variable, in method `main` of class `Runner`, you are changing for both *Paul* and *James*.

The simplest solution is to change the class constructor so that it creates a copy of the `hobbies` parameter and assigns the copy to the `hobbies` member:

```java
public People(int id, String name, List<String> hobbies) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.hobbies = new ArrayList<>(hobbies);
}
```

However, I suggest that you add methods to class `People` to manipulate `hobbies` member, including:

- `addHobby` for adding a hobby
- `removeHobby` for removing a hobby
- `clearHobbies` for removing all hobbies
- `getHobbies` that returns a copy of `hobbies` (so that code that calls the method cannot change `hobbies`)

Below code demonstrates.
Note that you should always use the interface – in this case `java.util.List` – rather than the implementation – in this case `ArrayList` – in the [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) so that you can change class `People` without having to change its API. If you change the API of class `People` then all other classes that use class `People` – like class `Runner` in the code in your question – will need to be changed as well.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class People {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> hobbies;

    public People(int id, String name, List<String> hobbies) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.hobbies = new ArrayList<>(hobbies);
    }

    public People(int id, String name) {
        this(id, name, new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    public People() {
        this(0, "");
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addHobby(String hobby) {
        if (!hobbies.contains(hobby)) {
            hobbies.add(hobby);
        }
    }

    public void clearHobbies() {
        hobbies.clear();
    }

    public List<String> getHobbies() {
        return List.of(hobbies.toArray(new String[]{}));
    }

    public void removeHobby(String hobby) {
        if (hobbies.contains(hobby)) {
            hobbies.remove(hobby);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "People [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", hobbies=" + hobbies + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<People> arrayPeople = new ArrayList<>();
        People paul = new People(1,"Paul");
        paul.addHobby("Football");
        paul.addHobby("Tennis");
        People james = new People(2,"James");
        james.addHobby("Football");
        james.addHobby("Tennis");
        james.addHobby("Golf");
        arrayPeople.add(paul);
        arrayPeople.add(james);

        System.out.println(arrayPeople);
    }
}
```

Running the above code prints the following:

```
[People [id=1, name=Paul, hobbies=[Football, Tennis]], People [id=2, name=James, hobbies=[Football, Tennis, Golf]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question seemed unclear to me, however I assume that you created lists such as

```
[name,age,location]
```

However, this is not an **object**. If you create a *person object*, you can add features inside it. So that when you create a person object, then you will have access to add/edit new features. In your case, your features must be:

- Name
- Age
- Location
- List (Whatever you name it, type of it must be an arraylist).

Comment: Attempted to clarify in the question

Comment: Edited again for further clarification

Answer (score 0):

To have a list of people:

```
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    String Address;
    ...
}
```

and
`ArrayList<Person>`

For the people class, if you need each hobby in hobbies to be unique you can have a `Set` class to store hobbies.

```
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    String address;
    Set<String> hobbies;
    ...
}
```

If the order does not matter you can use HashSet To maintain the order you can use TreeSet or LinkedHashSet.

```
class person{
    String name;
    int age;
    String address;
    TreeSet<String> hobbies;
    ...
}
```

```
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    String address;
    LinkedHashSet<String> hobbies;
    ...
}
```

To add a hobby to a person.

```
String hobby = "a hobby";
person.add(hobby);
```

To add hobbies to a person;

```
String hobby1 = "hobby1";
String hobby1 = "hobby2";
...
Set<String> hobbies = new TreeSet(); // or Set<String> hobbies = new LinkedHashMap();
hobbies.add(hobby1);
hobbies.add(hobby2);
...
person.addAll(hobby);
```

For another person with the same hobbies, you need to copy the hobbies, then modifying the hobbies of the second person will not affect the hobbies of the first person.

```
Set<String> new_hobbies = new TreeSet(old_hobbies); // or new LinkedHashSet(old_hobbies);
another_person.addAll(new_hobbies);
```

Comment: If I was to then add hobbies to a person, how would I go about it? Create an individual hobbies list with a different name per person?

Comment: So then for a second person in the overall list, how would I reset the hobby list for them without clearing the original?